# Why the product of 0.15 and 6 comes as 0.8999999... instead of 0.9 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, precision

In javascript, when I calculate `0.15*6`, I get `0.89999999` instead of `0.9`

I understand that this is due to the floating point arithmetic. But how can I avoid such problem and get correct result?

To add the relevance of this question, I will add my use case here.

I am provided with a **min**, **max** and **step** value all can be integer or floating point numbers. The input range `min - max` is not necessarily in multiple of the `step` value.

If the range is not a multiple of step, my task is to extend the range by adjusting (increasing) `max` value.

Example: min = `0`, max = `0.85`, step = `0.15`

Here the range = `0.85 - 0` = `0.85`, and this is not multiple of step value `0.15`. So I have to extend the `max` value.

I am using the below formula to get adjusted max value:

```js
max = Math.ceil((max - min) / step) * step + min;
```

I expect this to give

```
>> max = Math.ceil((0.85 - 0) / 0.15) * 0.15 + 0
>> max = Math.ceil(5.666666667) * 0.15
>> max = 6 * 0.15

>> max = 0.9 // <--- But, I get 0.8999999999999999 here
```

Please note that the number of decimal places are not known, therefore rounding is (probably) not an option.

Comment: As to getting a "correct" result: what's your application, that this tiiiiiny inaccuracy matters? If it's finance, you shouldn't be using floating point in the first place; keep everything in fixed-point integers (e.g. as cents).

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that issue based on your question's content, but your question's title doesn't match your actual question which is 'how can I avoid such problem and get correct result?'. I would rename this "how can I avoid floating point problems in JavaScript?"

Comment: An easy way to avoid this problem is to work with integers instead. This only applies to numbers where you know the amount of decimal numbers up front. A common example is money. € 1 = 100 euro cents. So change the calculations to always use euro cents instead. If something costs € 0,15 and you need 6 of them you would do 15 * 6 to calculate the amount of euro cents. If you need to convert it back to full euros for display purposes you simply divide by 100.

Comment: The correct solution is to use some kind of decimal number library in JavaScript.